# Should I ever use write_register() when write_registers() is more general (pyModbus)?

Tags: python, python-3.7, pymodbus

I'm starting to use pyModbus with Python 3.7.  In pyModbus.client.sync.ModbusTcpClient there are two methods for writing:

write_register()
write_registers()

Is there any benefit to using write_register() over write_registers() with a register list of 1 element?  Always using the latter would simplify my code but I thought I would check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modbus specification has two function codes to write to a holding registes `(0x06) Write Single Register` and  `(0x10)  Write Multiple registers` hence the two methods in pymodbus to write to the registers. The specs of the modbus device tells what function codes are supported and you will have to choose the corresponding method from the pymodbus client.

With `write_registers` it is possible to write a maximum of `123` registers in one shot , this is use-full when there is a need to write multiple registers in one call . If your requirement is to just to write to a single register the only advantage of `write_register` would be that you don't have to pass your value as a list .

The same explanation holds good for `write_coil` and `write_coils` methods as well.

Refer [modbus specs](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) for more details on the function code .

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I guessed as much: the only advantage of the Write Single... methods is that the parameter doesn't have to be passed as a list. Hence it is better in my code to call the Write Registers...methods (both for holding registers and coils) and make sure to pass lists even if they contain one element. Thanks!